# If $A$ and $B$ are matrices, what can we conclude if $AB = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A$ and $B$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices. If we know $AB$ = $BA$, what can we conclude from that?

I can think of three cases so far:

1. $A=B$: By Substitution on $A\times A=A\times A$, we get $AB=BA$
2. $A=I$ or $B=I$: If $B=I$, since $AI=IA=A$, $AB=BA$
3. $A$ or $B$ are filled with only zeros: A zero matrix multiplied by any other matrix in either direction is always a zero matrix.

Are there any cases I am missing? Any other information I can get out of this?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices)

Comment: $A=B^{-1}$. $A=f(B)$ where $B$ is a polynomial. $A=f(C)$ and $B=g(C)$ where  $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, etc.

Comment: If $AB = BA$ then $$e^A e^B = e^{A+B}$$ (using [matrix exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential?wprov=sfla1)). I think it is also the case that $AB = BA$ if $B = e^A$ or $A=e^B$ (i.e. a matrix commutes with its own exponential).

Comment: Also the obvious $AB=BA$ if $n=1$ :P

Comment: There are many many other cases, and there are many many things you can deduce from this relation. You can, however, try to prove that the only matrices $A$ such that $AB=BA$ *for all $B$* are of the form $\lambda I_n$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown wait, how do the polynomial stuff work? eg. Why is $AB=BA$ if $A=f(B)$?

Comment: @vikarjramun Think of an example. If $f(x)=3x^2-2x+1$ then $f(B)=3B^2-2B+I$. Would you agree that $Bf(B)=f(B)B=3B^3-2B^2+B$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Does the distributive property apply like that to matrices?

Comment: @vikarjramun Yes, distributivity holds for matrices.